# Solr Merge two queries and then do pagination

Tags: solr, solrj

Folks,

We have one requirement in solr where we want to merge results of two queries.

E.g
Query one returns [document1,document2,document3,document4]

Second Query returns [ document3,document4,document5,document6]

We want the result in following order [document1,document2,document3,document4,document5,document6]

Basically result from first query should take precedence and from second query it should remove duplicates.

We also want to do pagination at solr level as it returns 1 million documents for each query.

Queries :

1) How to create execute multiple queries together and get the results in order.
   (first queries result should appear first. from second query duplicate should be removed)

2) We want to paginate the data on entire resultset hence we cannot execute one by one. is there any way way we can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

1) You cannot do this in Solr. You'll have to add this logic at your app level.
 So, execute two solr queries normally as you would and then intersect the two sets.

2) Execute both queries with parameter `&rows=<no. of rows>`, so you end up getting only 5-10 rows per query (or as you wish) and then intersect these smaller sets.

Comment: Binoy thanks for you response. We want to do pagination as well so before hand we should know how many records are there from both queries (e.g. there are 1000 records we need to project like there are 10 pages with 100 items each). I feel it should be doable with some workaround

Comment: Some one is having any idea on this

Comment: @MihirkumarJoshi as Binoy says, if you want 100 items for each page you should just add a parameter rows=100&start=0. 
--- 
Then when user asks next page you just run the same query adding 100 to start parameter (rows=100&start=100 ; rows=100&start=200)...  
  
If you want to show the user how many pages are there, after first query you just compute numFound/rows rounded up (numFound is in solr response).  
---
This is for 1 query, as you want to merge two queries you should divide rows and start by 2 (rows=50&start=0/50/100...)